# Integração PC Telefone

Tags: delphi

Fazemos:

```
StringConexao ="ATDT"+numeroTelefone+ #13#10;
```

E fazemos

```
  WriteFile(
              hCommFile,
              PChar(StringConexao)[0],
              Length(s),
              NumberWritten,
              nil);
```

E a mágica é feita!
E o modem liga para um número.

Agora preciso fazer o contrário:

Ao receber um chamada, SIM, meu modem está recebendo chamadas quando alguém liga para o meu telefone, qual o comando, e em que situação chamar o comando para saber o número do telefone que está me ligando?

Se

```
  WriteFile()
```

É a responsável por fazer/receber  as ligações, então de qual parâmetro eu retiro o número da ligação?

Então,

No endereço:

http://support.usr.com/support/3cxm756/3cxm756-portuguese-ug/atcoms.htm

Na última linha, tem os últimos 2 comandos que são:

```
AT&Zn=s             Armazenar número telefônico

AT&Zn?              Exibir número telefônico
```

Como fazer para capturar então o número do telefone na estrutura da minha aplicação?

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, spBina;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    RadioButton1: TRadioButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;


var
 Form1: TForm1;
 hCommFile: THandle;
 Status: LongBool;


NumberWritten: DWORD;
Buf : array[0..1023] of Byte;
s :string;

implementation

uses ConvUtils;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//Testa os valores necessários
    begin

     //Abre a porta de comunicação
     s:='COM3';
     hCommFile := CreateFile (
                             PChar(s),
                             GENERIC_WRITE,
                             0, // não compartilhado
                             nil, // sem segurança
                             OPEN_EXISTING,
                             FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                             0);

     // Verifica a abertura da porta
    if hCommFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then

        begin
         memo1.lines.clear;
         memo1.lines.add('Não foi possível abrir a porta selecionada.');
         memo1.lines.add('Discagem não efetuada');
         CloseHandle(hCommFile);
        end

    else

        begin

         memo1.lines.clear;memo1.lines.add('Discando...');

         //Cria a string de comando
        if radiobutton1.checked then
         s:='ATDT'
        else
         s:='ATDP';

         s := s + Edit1.Text + #13#10;

         memo1.lines.add(s);

         //Envia a String de Comando
         NumberWritten:=0;

          WriteFile(
                        hCommFile,
                        PChar(s)[0],
                        Length(s),
                        NumberWritten,
                        nil);

         memo1.lines.add('Aguardando Atendimento ...');      
         MessageDlg('Retire o telefone do gancho e clique OK para desligar o modem',mtInformation,[mbok], 0);

         //Desconecta a ligação
         WriteFile(hCommFile,'ATH',5,NumberWritten, nil);

         //Fecha a porta de comunicação
         CloseHandle(hCommFile);memo1.lines.add('Modem Desconectado.'#13#10);
        end;
end;
end;
end.
```

Descobri que fazendo:

```
s := 'ATA+ #13#10;
```

Recebe a ligação:
Mas vem junto o barulho do modem
E ainda não consigo pegar o número do telefone

Comment: Você quer fazer uma URA ou algo do tipo?

Comment: Então, o objetivo é que ao receber uma ligação, o sistema possa ser capaz de identificar o número que está entrando. Depois, pega-se esse número e busco no banco para saber se há esse número cadastrado e retorna os dados do cadastro com aquele número!

Comment: Fazer uma aplicação que recebe chamadas telefônicas é algo **bastante complexo**. Se você já conseguiu receber a chamada, descobrir o número deve ser a parte mais fácil. Caso seja esse o caso, então edite a pergunta para explicar qual foi a dificuldade específica que teve.

Comment: O que eu preciso é exatamente captar na linha telefônica o número! Pelo menos um norte para pesquisar. O sistema é tranquilissimo de fazer! Já a captação do número........

Comment: Isto é um problema de hardware e não de programação (fora do escopo do site). Se for no Brasil, precisa de um conversor DTMF que faça a conversão para o pc. No exterior, os fax-modems até funcionam em alguns casos, pois lá a "BINA" é FSK. Aqui no Brasil é DTMF

Comment: Sim, esse  conversor DTMF é um equipamento que fica entre o PC e no meio da linha? Se for, após essa conexão, algum componente do Delphi já consegue identificar? Qual componente?

Comment: @CarlosRocha adicione esses detalhes de FSK e DTMF na pergunta e ela poderá ser reaberta.

Comment: @Renan 1, desculpe, não entendi muito bem o que você disse!

Comment: Pronto! Editei!

Answer (score 0):

Tem muita coisa acontecendo junto, vamos separar as coisas:

## 1 - Comandos AT

O que você está fazendo é mandando comandos **AT** para a **porta serial** do modem. Você não está efetivamente fazendo nada, você está dando comandos para seu hardware fazer alguma coisa pra você.

Os comandos AT são incríveis, existe uma lista enorme de comandos disponíveis, mas uma parte muito chata é que os hardwares normalmente não implementam todos do comandos do set de comandos disponível.

Isso não quer dizer que seu hardware é bom ou ruim por implementar mais comandos ou menos comandos, na verdade existem comandos para todo tipo de coisas, desde o básico que é discar um número (é o que você está usando), até  verificar nível de bateria do dispositivo, verificar o estado atual de algum registrador interno do hardware, criar um conexão GPRS, listar as redes disponíveis, estabelecer uma conexão GPRS, enviar e receber SMS, etc. Não faz sentido implementar os set de comandos que são específicos para SMS em um modem Dial Up de um PC, assim como não faz sentido implementar comandos referentes a ligação telefônica em um modem 3G USB.

Mesmo em dispositivos similares, como modems 3G USB (vou falar mais de modem 3G USB, pois eu estudei mais eles quando implementei minha classe e envio e recebimento de SMS pelo Delphi usando comandos AT), você não tem o mesmo set de comandos implementado em todos os equipamentos, isso porque depende do suporte do hardware e da implementação do fabricante (hardwares mais simples - ou seja, baratos - têm recursos mais limitados que hardwares mais completos. Isso é bem compreensivel). Para superar isso é preciso implementar uma rotina que verifique a disponibilida dos comandos no hardware que você está usando e tratar o tipo de suporte que você vai dar, ou ainda se seu software vai funcionar com o hardware em questão. No meu caso com o SMS pelo modem 3G eu tive muito problema no començo porque em casa usava um dispositivo, mas os clientes usavam outros diferentes e a aplicação quebrava direto.

Veja, será preciso estudar o set de comandos AT e ir testando os comandos com seu hardware. Mas já vou adiantar que se for uma placa de faz modem "win modem" você terá um conjunto de recursos muito, muito limitado. Lá nos primórdios da internet (década de 90, eu vivi isso) os faz modems eram dispositivos completos de conexão, mas com o passar do tempo os chineses foram removendo os recursos menos usados para baratear o hardware até que sobrou unica e exclusivamente o necessário para uma conexão de internet discada (na verdade o winmodem nem é um modem, mas nem vou entrar nesse assunto aqui).

Se você não tem um winmodem é uma grande vantagem, mas como eu disse antes, os recursos foram sendo retirados dos hardwares aos poucos até não sobrar nada, então os recursos que seu dispositivos tem vão depender de qual ponto ele está nesse processo de sucateamento que houve.

#### Aqui vão uns links sobre comandos AT:

https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf

http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/modem.html

http://www.mt-system.ru/sites/default/files/simcom_sim5320_atc_en_v1.23.pdf

## 2-Identificação de chamadas e Atender Ligações

Eu não sei se você já estudou essa parte de identificação de chamadas, mas a informação do número que está te ligando vem em um trem DTMF antes do primeiro toque do telefone. A identificação da chamada **depente crucialmente** de 2 fatores:

**A -** Deve haver o serviço de identificação de chamadas ativo na sua linha telefônica, ou seja, se a operadora não te mandar o trem DTMF antes do primeiro toque você não tem como saber quem está te ligando. Antigamente isso era um serviço cobrado à parte, mas hoje em dia é bem mais comum e muitas operadoras nem cobram mais por isso, mas é bom você verificar se você tem esse serviço disponível, se ele está ativo e principalmente se ele está funcionando corretamente. Faça o teste conectando na linha um aparelho telefônico que tenha o recurso de identificação de chamadas (e que você esteja certo que está funcionando kkk) e ligue do seu celular para a linha em questão.

**B -** Seu modem precisa decodificar o trem DTMF que a operadora manda. Eu particularmente acho essa parte bem difícil, não é que eu esteja torcendo contra, mas é que os modem foram perdendo recursos (lembra que comentei aí  acima?) e esse foi um dos primeiros recursos a ser removido, pois ele não interfere em nada na conexão discada. Agora mesmo se você tiver a sorte de ter um modem que não foi capado nesse recurso, existe um outro problema que é bem complicado: o padrão brasileiro de identificação de chamada. Os modems não são fabricados no Brasil, normalmente são fabricados na China e seguem os padrões do mercado norte americado de telecomunicações. Não existe somente um tipo de identificação de chamadas, normalmente nós usamos aqui no Brasil o padrão DTMF, mas existem outros padrões diferentes e o mais comum no mercado norte americano é o FSK. Se você tiver um modem que tenha o recurso de identificação de chamadas, mas que não aceite o mesmo padrão que sua linha telefônica manda, você não terá sucesso no uso do recurso. Mas como as coisas mudaram nos últimos anos, hoje em dia temos operadoras no Brasil que usam o FSK, então pode ser que dê certo. Veja, se você for analisar essa parte é quase uma roleta russo, tem várias variáveis no caminho.

Se seu modem conseguir decodificar o sinal da identificação de chamadas da sua linha, aí você precisará usar o comando AT específico para solicitar ao modem o número que ele recebeu (você se lembra que, quem faz o trabalho sujo é o modem, você usa os comandos AT para interfacear com ele). Eu não sei qual é o comando, mas consultando a documentação você acha isso.

Para atender a chamada você vai precisar ficar monitorando o status do modem te tempo em tempo (a cada 2 segundos, por exemplo) mandando um comando AT que vai retornar se a linha está tocando e caso a resposta seja sim, vai ter que mandar um comando AT para atender a chamada. Depois de atender você vai precisar colocar um áudio na linha, certo? Como você vai fazer isso? Eu sinceramente não sei, nunca cheguei tão longe. kkk

Com minha experiência em eletrônica e telecom (trabalhei quase uns 10 anos com isso), sei que você poderia injetar um áudio na linha usando um acoplamento capacitivo, através de um capacitor de 1 microfarad, o modem garante o enlace da linha enquanto você não der o comando AT para desligar a ligação. Mas isso já entra em hardware e dependendo de como você fizer existe uma grande chance de dar ruido na ligação telefônica. Não vou me estender nesse aspecto.

## 3 - Identificador de chamadas à parte

Eu não sei exatamente como você pretende tratar a chamada depois de identificá-la e atendê-la, mas se eu considerar que você tem um bom plano para essa parte, uma opção para desviar do problema de identificação de chamadas do modem é ter um dispositivo de identificação de chamadas à parte conectado na linha e ler dele o número de quem está te ligando e, dependendo dos recursos que ele oferecer, saber por ele se há uma chamada tocando (pode ser que seu modem não dê suporte a saber se a linha telefônica está tocando).

Existem opções de mercado prontas, mas eu acho elas muito caras. De qualquer forma você pode dar uma conferida:

https://lista.mercadolivre.com.br/identificador-de-chamadas-para-pc-usb

Se você não está disposto a pagar essa grana toda, uma opção é se aventurar com o Arduino e construir o seu próprio identificador de chamadas, você vai ver que o circuito é muito simples, basicamente é um CI que faz tudo e você só precisa lê-lo. Aqui vai uns links que falam do tema:

http://labdegaragem.com/forum/topics/bina-com-dtmf

http://labdegaragem.com/forum/topics/dtmf-com-arduino

Eu tenho mais coisas que poderia falar sobre o tema, mas estou sem tempo agora (escrevi um textão, hein? É que me empolgo com esse tema kkk), mas se tiver mais alguma coisa que precise de mim é só comentar que eu volto e continuamos.